# ABPerson in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, abaddressbook

I'm trying to figure out to store a reference to an ABPerson in a Core Data store on an iPhone app.  Ultimately, I'd like to be able to sync with a Mac version of the app (I'm assuming ABRecordIDs wouldn't be the same for the iPhone and the Mac).  I was thinking of storing the record ID, name, and email and checking against those--is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, I don't want to sync the actual contact, just a reference to the contact, but I can't figure out a way to do that without a name and/or email lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of sounds like you're attempting to out-guess or re-do the syncing functionality Apple's already implemented. Can you describe exactly what you mean by "sync with a Mac version of the app"?

If you're asking for a better way to store the information about an `ABPerson` to make it easy to recover the next app launch, there is a property in `ABPerson`, `kABUIDProperty`, which will give you a unique identifier for the record that is guaranteed not to change. I used something similar with an app that uses the Media Player Framework to identify exact songs between launches.

Comment: kABUIDProperty isn't available on the iPhone, unless the docs are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kABPersonCreationDateProperty instead of kABUIDProperty, which is available in iOS.